# Geoserver, OpenScales and flex 3

Tags: geoserver, flex, openscales

I am using GeoServer, OpenScales Flex 3 for my web-mapping application, is there any source for the Flex OpenScales API to display the maps.

additional from a comment

I am working on a project to display the weather data in online. I have loaded point and polygon shapefiles into PostGIS and created a PostGIS store in GeoServer. Using Adobe Flex 3 and OpenScales i have designed and displayed the both shapefile as WMS and WFS. Now i want to display animated GIF in the map. any idea....

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **Openscales core API documentation** - quite abstract for all of this documentation:

http://openscales.org/api/current/openscales-core/

Openscales Core flash-10.1
http://openscales.org/api/current/openscales-core-flash-10.1/

OpenScales Flex
http://openscales.org/api/current/openscales-fx/

others

OpenScales Geometry
http://openscales.org/api/current/openscales-geometry/

Projections
http://openscales.org/api/current/openscales-proj4as/

Comment: Sir/Madam, Actually i have used the Flex API for OpenScales, now I am struck up with displaying the Animated GIFs. Any idea to display it..

Comment: Can you add that to your original question please.

Comment: Sir/Madam, I am working on a project to display the weather data in online. I have loaded point and polygon shapefiles into PostGIS and created a PostGIS store in GeoServer. Using Adobe Flex 3 and OpenScales i have designed and displayed the both shapefile as WMS and WFS. Now i want to display animated GIF in the map.  any idea....                  thanks in advance

Comment: I am facing problem in styling the WFS layer in the OpenScales [link](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/22745/styling-the-wfs-point-layer-openscales-1-1-flex-3),     Can you help me from this, Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

@kishor, the problem you're having is due to the Flex framework not natively supporting animated GIF (it does support GIF, just not *animated* GIF). In other words, you won't be able to use animated GIF without going behind the back of the framework.

However, it seems there are options available to you. Check out the [AS3GIF library](http://code.google.com/p/as3gif/) composed by [Thibault Imbert](http://code.google.com/u/thibault.imbert/) of [ByteArray.org](http://www.bytearray.org/) fame (most known for his contribution of [AlivePDF](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/), a library for rendering PDF files directly from ActionScript3).

There is a [short tutorial at creative-geeks.com](http://creative-geeks.com/blog/2010/06/30/using-animating-gifs-in-flex-and-flash/) demonstrating how to implement AS3GIF in your Flex/AS3 application. I've had good experiences working with Thibault's libs, so I have every confidence this should get you through the hoop.